# SVN: delete folder completely from version control

Tags: svn, repository, directory

In a subversion project there are the folders "de_de" and "de_DE" checked-in in some directory.

The "de_de" folder isn't really needed and  is causing problems now when I want to checkout the project on a OSX working machine because in contrast to the Debian Testserver there are no two folders with the names "de_de" and "de_DE" allowed in the same directory.

I have absolutely no idea how I can solve this situation without creating a new repository which isn't an option.

I removed that "de_de" folder from version control on the Debian machine, commited the changes and checked out the new revision on the working machine.

But when I try to commit something I still get that error:

```
 svn: E155015: Aborting commit: '....../de_de' remains in conflict
```

Is there any possibility that the repository "forgets" about that folder completely?

Answer (score 1):

You have the conflict - tell SVN that conflict is resolved:

```
svn resolved de_de
```